# Create a luxon DateTime while keeping the original timezone offset

Tags: javascript, luxon

If I have the following ISO date:

```
2021-07-05T13:20:00+06:00
```

If I call `DateTime.FromISO` it will convert it to machine local time, I then have to parse the string and set the zone manually.

How do I create a luxon `DateTime` object with the offset of +06:00 as in the parsed string without the extra work?

Please note, I know I can use `DateTime.fromISO(isoDate, { zone: 'utc' });` or any other zone, but do I have to really parse the iso string and get the zone manually to pass it to the `{zone: }` option?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found it:

```
const date = DateTime.fromISO("2021-07-05T13:20:00+06:00", { setZone: true });
```

the `setZone: true` option will take care of that.

Comment: Thanks - this was not easy to find in the documentation.

Comment: FYI you can accept your answer, this can be useful for people in the future looking for accepted answers.